# Change Size of Additional Flextable Header

Tags: r, flextable

I have been using `add_header_lines()` to add a header to my flextable. I would like this header to have a different text format than the table as a whole. Unfortunately, when I use `fontsize()` it formats text for both the header and the column names. Is there a way to *only* change the text format for the header produced with `add_header_lines()`?

Here is some sample code:

```
df <- data.frame(crime = c("assault", "homicide", "burglary"),
                 Jan = c(5, 2, 7),
                 Feb = c(2, 4, 0),
                 Mar = c(1, 2, 1))

flex <- flextable(df)

flex <- add_header_lines(flex, values = "This is a header")
flex <- fontsize(flex, size = 15, part = "header")
```

As you can see, the `fontsize` function affects both the added header and the column values. Any idea of how to change just the headers text format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the selector `i`.

```
library(flextable)

df <- data.frame(crime = c("assault", "homicide", "burglary"),
                 Jan = c(5, 2, 7),
                 Feb = c(2, 4, 0),
                 Mar = c(1, 2, 1))

flex <- flextable(df)

flex <- add_header_lines(flex, values = "This is a header")
flex <- fontsize(flex, size = 15, part = "header", i = 1)
flex <- color(flex, color = "red", part = "header", i = 1)
flex
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks David! I had tried this argument before bust must have made a mistake because I thought it didn't work. It is exactly what I was hoping for, thank you!